# Speeding up insert with large number of columns (Pandas, MySQL and Sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, performance, sqlalchemy

I'm importing financial data into MySQL from a pandas DataFrame using sqlalchemy. The number of columns is large (over 600). The code was initially

```
sql_data.to_sql(name='FinanceData', con=connection, if_exists='append', method='multi', index=True,
                        index_label=('Datetime', ''))
```

This took an unacceptably long time.

After researching for a while, I found out that `method='multi'` improves performance unless the data has many columns. Sure enough, deleting it sped up the insertions drastically. However, this left me wondering if there's any way to get the performance benefit of inserting multiple rows simultaneously without running into the same issue. Any suggestions on how I could speed up this insertion further?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `pandas` and `sqlalchemy` were both built for convenience, not for speed.  How hard would it be for you to create the SQL yourself, since you know what the datatypes are?

Comment: MySQL's fastest load of a single table is via `LOAD DATA` from a CSV file.  Does pandas use that or something slower?

Comment: @RickJames I believe it uses something slower, although I could just save the data to a CSV and then load it into MySQL. Thanks for the tip!